# Getting Null after extracting data from HDFS in Hive?

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

What have I done so far is, I've setup Hadoop and Hive in my linux enviroment and I'm trying to extract data from an HDFS file into my Hive table.

This is how the log line looks like:

> apache 2013-10-09T14:04:32Zphp129.124.201.110/EKEE.php20019705910Mozilla/5.0
>   (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/11.0.696.50 Safari/534.24

This my Hive query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE LogParserSample(
logtype STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 'input.regex' = '^[^0-9]+'
) 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/mypath/';
```

When I did execute the above the table got created successfully. But then when I tried to query the data from that table using a **SELECT** statement, I'm getting null instead of the word apache. For this instance, I'm trying to extract the word **apache** from the above log line. But then I tried executing the same regex in [rubular](http://rubular.com/), the outcome was correct as I expected. I'm unable to figure out why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'input.regex' = '^([^0-9]+).*'
```

1. Only expressions surrounded by brackets are mapped to columns.
2. The whole record should be covered by the regex

---

```
create external table logparsersample
(
    logtype string
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
with serdeproperties (
 'input.regex' = '^([^0-9]+).*'
) 
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select * from LogParserSample
;
```

---

```
+---------+
| logtype |
+---------+
| apache  |
+---------+
```